# Why do I see different files/folders when open desktop with terminal "li -a" vs desktop + "cmd+shift+."?

Tags: terminal, zsh, directory, ls, desktop

When I run the terminal and type "ls -a", and what I see is a lot of additional file starting with a dot as it is supposed to be:

[image]

However, when I try to visualize the hidden files with graphical interface by pressing "cmd+shift+." I don't find files starting with a dot, instead I find different files that I don't see in the terminal when I use "ls -a":

[image]

Why that might be and how to see all the files in the terminal/finder/desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Those 2 images are showing 2 different folders.**

- The first image (using ls -a) is showing you your personal folder.
- The second image is showing you the files & folders in the Desktop folder.

Try this:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ls -a
```

And notice that you will see the contents as per the second image.

Notice that both have a folder called Documents, and so perhaps you have 2 such folders?  The following would make that obvious:

```
cd ~
ls -la
```

Comment: That's right. Turned out to be a very silly question. Anyway, thank you for your help!